# Error feeding value to read.csv: Must be character string

Tags: r, csv

I have a function defining a directory and a file(s) to be loaded and analyzed. 
The values are being read in by the function, but when called by `read.csv`,  it does not seem to recognize the file name.  I believe it is an issue with the format, but I don't know.  Everything seems to be doing what it should except the dt `Selectdata` is never created `Selectdata<-read.csv(z, header=TRUE)`. `z` being a vector containing file name to be loaded.

When debugging this is the generated error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

As the error said the value being read is not a character, string or connection, I tired to set it `as.character` and such but to no avail.  It must be something more simple i am missing.

When run:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(Selectdata$polutant, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

But, really, `Selectdata` is never created (so, mean is attempted, but obviously has no value)

```
testfun <- function(directory, polutant, id) {

    setwd(directory)         
    x <- polutant     # not needed just checking to see if polutant has been read  
    print(x)          # not needed just checking  

    y <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)

    print(y[id])      # not needed just checking
    z <- y[id]

    if (length(id == 1)) {
        Selectdata <- read.csv(z, header = TRUE)
    }
    mean(Selectdata$polutant, na.rm=TRUE) 
}
```

Comment: So what is being printed in your `print(y[id])` line? (There are more errors though)

Comment: If you search stack overflow for "[r] pollutant" you can see all the questions your classmates are asking and use some of those answers as well.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick - I appreciate your indulgence with our intrusion..  I hope one day I can return the favor(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, not necessarily related to your error message. Still, let’s take them in turn, the result may make it obvious where the error is:

```
x <- polutant     # not needed just checking to see if polutant has been read  
print(x)          # not needed just checking
```

Not an error, but no need to assign `polutant` to another variable. Just `print` it directly.

```
y <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
```

You specify `directory` as the directory, but you already `chdir`’d into `directory`. So now you’re looking in `directory/directory`. Consequently, you’ll probably not find your files.

Since `chdir` has a side-effect observable outside the function, it’s not a good idea to use it anyway. Remove it.

```
print(y[id])      # not needed just checking
```

What does this print? Probably `NULL` – which causes the error message.

```
if (length(id == 1)) {
```

*First* you compare `id` to `1`, *then* you check whether the length of that is unequal to 0 (`if (some_number)` is a sloppy shortcut for `if (some_number != 0)`). What you wanted to write is `if (length(id) == 1)`.

```
mean(Selectdata$polutant, na.rm=TRUE)
```

There are two errors here. Firstly, you cannot access `SelectData` outside the scope it’s been defined in (i.e. inside the `if`). Secondly, this will try to access a column in the data frame with the name `polutant`. What you probably want is to access the column with the name that’s stored *in the variable `polutant`*. You cannot use the `$` syntax for that, you need to use either `Selectdata[[polutant]]` or `Selectdata[, polutant]`.

Which leaves us with:

```
testfun <- function(directory, polutant, id) {
    filenames <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)

    if (length(id) == 1) {
        filename <- filenames[id]
        selectdata <- read.csv(filename, header = TRUE)
        mean(selectdata[, polutant], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
}
```

(I’ve taken the liberty of unifying the variable naming and formatting convention, and using more descriptive variable names.)

Also, be aware that `list.files` returns filenames in unspecified, and potentially changing order, so you cannot meaningfully use a fixed `id` to load a given file.

Comment: Looks like the two significant issues were indeed: 1) (length(id) == 1), where I had the parentheses in the wrong place so it was skipping the entire "if" statement  2) mean(selectdata[, polutant], na.rm = TRUE) syntax and 3) defining outside the "if".  Your code works.  Thanks for the help: I apologize for the spurious code, I was dropping stuff in to try to see where the code was working and were it was failing.  I will clean it up better next time.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that `z` could be anything other than a character vector with a filename based on the code you supplied. Are you sure that's exactly what you ran and that's the exact error you got?

Objects you only create inside of `if` statements disappear after that block exists. For example

```
> if(1==2) {
+     a<-"ok"
+ }
> a;
Error: object 'a' not found
```

Why not put the `mean(Selectdata$polutant, na.rm=TRUE)` inside the `if` statement as well?

Comment: Thanks, yes, thats something i didn't realize about the {}.  I put the mean outside trying to deal with both parts of the question: where there is one file or multiple files being appended together I looked to see if the file length was = 1 and drop to a simple mean or if filelength>1 I drew in multiple files, rbind them and perform the mean function.  I will just write the mean line in both parts of the if/else.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting yesterday and came up with one that I think works quite well.  It uses `dir` instead of pasting the path to file together with `paste` and `list.files`.  Since I've never seen `dir` used nor used it myself, I cannot tell you whether its performance is better than pasting the file names together, but it seems to work well for this example.

The result is a list of the columns which were calculated, the mean, and the column means.  I did this to show what is being calculated in the function.  It can easily be changed to output only the mean of all columns.

The function:

```
multifile.means <- function(directory = getwd(), pollutant, id = NULL)
{
  d <- match.arg(directory, list.files())
  cn <- match.arg(pollutant,  c('sulfate', 'nitrate'))
  ## list the full file paths in the given 'directory'
  p <- dir(d, full.names = TRUE)
  ## subset 'p' based on 'id' values
  if(!is.null(id)){ id <- id[!id > length(p)];  p <- p[id] }
  ## read, store, and name the relevant columns
  cl <- sapply(p, function(x){ read.csv(x)[,cn] }, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  colnames(cl) <- basename(p)
  ## return a named list of results
  list(values = cl, 
       mean = mean(cl, na.rm = TRUE), 
       colMeans = colMeans(cl, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

The result (with default `ID = NULL`, meaning to calculate all files in the directory):

```
> multifile.means('testDir', 'sulfate')
$values
      001.csv 057.csv 146.csv 213.csv
 [1,]       2       2       5       1
 [2,]       9       4       4       4
 [3,]       6       9       5       7
 [4,]      10       2       5       4
 [5,]       9       9      NA      NA
 [6,]      10       6       2       5
 [7,]       4       4       2      NA
 [8,]       5       4       7       4
 [9,]       3       9       1       8
[10,]       4       2       1       2

$mean
[1] 4.864865

$colMeans
 001.csv  057.csv  146.csv  213.csv 
6.200000 5.100000 3.555556 4.375000
```